# Rotate figure and caption with floatrow

Tags: floats, rotating, floatrow

I have a problem with my LaTeX code:

I want two things:

1. Besides "normal" figures with the figure in the middle and the caption below, I want some pictures be rotated (because of their size) to fit the page in landscape view and the caption still below the picture, thus also rotated.
2. I also need some pictures on the left or right of the page and the caption on the side of them.

First, I was able to do 1. via `rotatebox`. But to get my captions next to the figures, I added the package `floatrow`, which seems to cause that the captions for case 1. are not rotated anymore. 
Below you find the reduced code, including the `floatrow` package. Can someone help me and explain, why `floatrow` cancels the rotation of the caption and provide me with a work around?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{tgadventor}
 \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{subfigure}
 \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
 \usepackage{placeins}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{floatflt}
 \usepackage{wrapfig}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
 \usepackage{appendix}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{paralist}
 %\usepackage{flafter}
 \usepackage{ifthen}
 \usepackage{mathptmx}
 \usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\rotatebox{90}{%
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textheight}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{picthatshouldberotated.pdf}
\caption[setupt]{text.}
\label{fig:setup}
\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,top},capbesidewidth=8cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{  \caption[thingy]{thingy}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{picwithcaptionnextoit.png}}
\label{fig:thingy}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `sidewaysfigure` environment from the `rotating` package. This will place the rotated figure on a separate page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-16x10.pdf}
\caption[setupt]{text.}
\label{fig:setup}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,top},capbesidewidth=8cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]
{  \caption[thingy]{thingy}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}}
\label{fig:thingy}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ahhh very nice, also the auto alignment to the outer side of the document :) Thanks a lot